# Horizontal Scroll for UISegmentedControll

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I have stuck with a problem regarding `UISegmentedControl` and `UIScrollView`. In my project the requirement is to add 7 segments in `UISegmentedControl` and the scrolling should be done in horizontal way ignorer to select all the available 7 segments. Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Don't use a segment but a scrollview or collection view ?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl

Comment: Thanks Nishant, it worked for me.

Comment: @Nishant, any swift compatible libraries like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A system segmented control can't do that. You'll need to use a 3rd party library or write your own. @Nishant gave you a link to a github repo in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

So you need a few steps:

- set scroll view `content size` to width: page width * page count, height;
- handle `scrollView:didScroll` and calculate current position of scroll and change selected segmented control;
- handle scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: and handle case when scroll end in the middle of page and move `contentOffset` for beginning of the page (decide which one);
- handle segmentedControl tap and setContentOffset:animated to scroll for selected page